# Cannot access global variable defined in one JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two JS files - `first.js` and `second.js`.

`first.js` contains some common library functions while `second.js` is the actual code which uses them.

The structure of `first.js` is something like this -

```
var globalObj = {};

(function($){

  globalObj.data = {};

  globalObj.func1 = function(){

  };

  globalObj.func2 = function(){

  };
  //......
})(jQuery)
```

My `second.js` looks like this -

```
(function($){

 function init(){
     console.log(globalObj);
     var val1 = globalObj.func1();
     globalObj.func3 = function(){

     };
 }

 $(document).ready(function(){
     init();
 });
})(jQuery)
```

As seen above, in `second.js`, I want to use the functions defined in the `first.js` and also add some more functions to `globalObj`.

My problems are -

1. I am getting an error in `first.js` where `globalObj.data` is declared - `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'data' of undefined`.
2. In the `console.log(globalObj)` inside `init()` of `second.js`, I am getting an empty object while I am expecting it to show the contents of `globalObj` as defined in `first.js`.

The point is, In `second.js`, I want to use and modify the same global variable declared and defined inside `first.js`. How can I do that? Also, please note that, it is mandatory for me to use the anonymous self-executing function blocks present in both the JS files. Please help.

`first.js` is called before `second.js`.

Comment: try putting `console.log('1./2. file')` in the beginning of each file you include. Do they coming out in the right order?

Comment: @2astalavista, yes they come in the right order, `first.js` is called before `second.js`.

Comment: OK, but your example does not contain any `X.data = Y` part, that couses error (in the 2nd.js)

Comment: You must be doing something that isn't shown in the question, that's causing the problem. I suggest removing second.js, then start removing sections of code until first.js starts working, or until all that is left is the section shown in the question (which should work).

Comment: @MrCode, you are right. There was `var globalObj = globalObj || {}` inside the anonymous scope of `first.js`